# How to Check all AD users for "blank" password?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I check all users in the AD for a blank password?
**AND** Filter them....

I know how to check all user but I can't Filter them...

Here is what I have:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU,DC=mydomain,DC=forest,DC=local" | ForEach {
   $_.SamAccountName
   (new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "", ("domain\" + $_.SamAccountName), "").psbase.name -ne $null
   Write-Host ""
}
```

Now I want to know how to filter the Output...

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to do that natively.

DS Internals Test-PaswordQuality:

https://github.com/MichaelGrafnetter/DSInternals/blob/master/Documentation/PowerShell/Test-PasswordQuality.md#test-passwordquality

Install-Module -Name DSInternals -Force

There is also a free application here that uses DSInternals:

https://thycotic.com/solutions/free-it-tools/weak-password-finder/

Answer (score 6):

You can find users where PasswordLastSet is null:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU,DC=mydomain,DC=forest,DC=local" -Properties PasswordLastSet | where { $_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null}
```

Comment: Does this exclude users which had an initial password set when created but never changed it (e.g. because they haven't logged in yet)?

Comment: Yes, when you create a user and set an initial password, the PasswordLastSet attribute is updated, and not `null`. However, if the user must change his password at next logon, this attribute will be null too !

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following the get the results with a True or False, stating that the users has a blank password or not:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=someOU,DC=your,DC=domain" | ForEach {    $_.SamAccountName    (new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "", ("domain\" + $_.SamAccountName), "").psbase.name -ne $null    Write-Host "" }
```